# layered navigation filters

Tags: layered-navigation

Is there any way to get the url to only load one filter

Let me brief a bit. I am talking about one filter say size

I have modified the filters to select multiple items at a time

But if a user has selected 3 out of 6 filters. and now the user wants to select only 4th filter. when user clicks on the that link across the 4th filter all the other 3 active filters should clear and select only 4th filter.

```
$_item->getUrl();
$_item->getRemoveUrl();
```

But all these urls will have the active filters in them. Is there any Magento method for this?

Or should I do little tweeking??

I used `$_item->getValueString()` to get the values, but it always return the current active  plus the filter. Since the price bucket already have `,` I am not able to use that as delimiter while exploding. Anybody know how to change the `,` to some any other character in method `$_item->getValueString()`

Comment: you tweaked already. Magento can't handle multiple values out of the box, so go on your way :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove all filters from your URL.
The block that does that is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State` with the method

```
public function getClearUrl()
{
    $filterState = array();
    foreach ($this->getActiveFilters() as $item) {
        $filterState[$item->getFilter()->getRequestVar()] = $item->getFilter()->getCleanValue();
    }
    $params['_current']     = true;
    $params['_use_rewrite'] = true;
    $params['_query']       = $filterState;
    $params['_escape']      = true;
    return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', $params);
}
```

which in turn uses

```
public function getActiveFilters()
{
    $filters = $this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters();
    if (!is_array($filters)) {
        $filters = array();
    }
    return $filters;
}
```

So it iterates over all set filters and unsets them in the query.
You could do it exactly like this also from the filter block. Or you can try to access the state block and call the getCleanUrl() method.

Comment: how will i call `getClearLinkUrl` from my filter.phtml?

Comment: `getRemoveUrl` removes the filter from the url, but i want that filter in url with all others removed.I tried with `getValueString` but that gives u the active filters also as a sting

Comment: @zamil I updated my answer to shed some light on how to reset the URL to have no filters set.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But my pbm is not getting the clear url. I already have the clear url in my filter.phtml.  I am not able to append the only filter criteria to that clear url when there are already many filters are active.And i am trying to do this in filter.phtml

Comment: please see my question edit